# Appending option to select field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using this code:

```
var tempObj = {
    "noselected" : "",
    "option1": "item1",
    "option2": "item2",
    "option3": "item3"
};

$.each(tempObj, function (val, text) {
            $(this).append($('<option />', {
                value: val,
                text: text
            }));
        });
```

but when that code is executed I obtain the following error:

```
TypeError: n.createDocumentFragment is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...eturn t?u.length:u?nt.error(e):L(e,a).slice(0)}function at(e,t,r){var i=t.dir,s=...
```

And only the first element is not appended.

Comment: change `$(this)` to reference the `select` - `$('select#someId').append(...)`

Comment: `.append()` is specified for inserting nodes into the DOM. You'll need to use a selector to grab the `select` element on the page, then iterate over the tempObj within the handler.

Comment: The append seems to work partially.

Comment: $(this) is associated to my select element

Comment: in $.each statement, `this` refers to individual items in the list (that $.each in iterating on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it this way -

```
$.each(tempObj, function (val, text) {
    $('<option />', {
        value: val,
        text: text
    }).appendTo('select');
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/zKkXp/2/

As of your comment - you are doing that in click handler and trying to access clicked select with `this` inside `each` , You can do it this way -

```
$('select').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.each(tempObj, function (val, text) {
        $this.append($('<option />', {
            value: val,
            text: text
        }));
    });
});
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/zKkXp/4/

Comment: Thank you @pXL but I need to refer to this. Can I?

Comment: @Joseph82 , No, `this` doesn't refer to your select _in your loop_. anyway- why do you need to refer `this` ?

Comment: cause my code is inside this $("select").on('click',function(){ ... }); so I need to refer to exactly the select I have clicked on.

Comment: @Joseph82 , Well, if that is the case , Yes you can do it this way `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/zKkXp/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(tempObj, function (val, text) {
    $('select').append($('<option>', { 
        value: val,
        text : text 
    }));
});
```